# Do all Canadian preferred stocks for retail investors trade on stock exchanges?

Tags: canada, preferred-stocks

In Canada, do all retail-investor-accessible preferred stocks (i.e. those preferred stocks that can be bought by retail investors) trade on stock exchanges (e.g. on the Toronto Stock Exchange)? Or is there something like the over-the-counter market in the US where some preferred stock issues do not trade on stock exchanges?